# Not able to GET object key data in JSON-SERVER

Tags: javascript, json, rest, http, json-server

I'm trying to make a get request to json-server to get in a nested object. But it is returning an empty response instead of the object key data.

I have gone through the documentation and there is nothing specific to the db structure that I have.

I want to filter the model array but not getting the model data.

my db.json file is

```
  {
      "data": {
          "model": 
            [
               {
                  "name": "BERLINGO",
                  "manufacturerName": "CITREON",
                  "id": 1
              },
              {
                  "name": "C3",
                  "manufacturerName": "CITREON",
                  "id": 2
              }
          ]
      }
  }
```

For GET /data , I'm getting the following response.

```
{
  "model": [
    {
      "name": "BERLINGO",
      "manufacturerName": "CITREON",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "C3",
      "manufacturerName": "CITREON",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

GET call for /data/model is giving an empty object.

{}

Comment: Where is the code for the call you are making?

Comment: I'm just making a GET call directly from the browser URL bar as of now to test  if I'm getting the data. Eventually, I'll be doing it inside my react app with axios

Comment: Is there any log at console?

Comment: @JDLozano yes, in the chrome netwrok tab, it has the 404 error, same in the json-server, i.e. the 404 error for the request /data/model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `json-server` does not support such "nested value" syntax. You can `GET /data`, but cannot `GET /data/model` or `GET /data.model`. All you can do is fetching the whole `/data` object and access `model` field of it.

This is already [discussed](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/814) in `json-server`'s GitHub Repo, and according to an older [discussion](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/359), it seems the owner of `json-server` (@typicode) does not intend to make this support.